# Sum Average Min Max without using inbuild functions or Methods in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I wrote a program for calculating Sum, Average, Min & Max without inbulit functions or Methods. I found many techniques and locked in the below one.
But the problem is, while doing in normal ways. Result came.
While transferring into a windows form, I am unable to get the output. It always throws error.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int n = int.Parse(textBox7.Text);
int[] numbers = new int[n];
int sum = 0;
float average;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
numbers[i] = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
}
Array.Sort(numbers);

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
sum += numbers[i];
}

average = ((float)sum / n);

textBox4.Text = numbers[0].ToString();
textBox5.Text = numbers[-1].ToString();
textBox2.Text = sum.ToString();
textBox3.Text = average.ToString();
}
```

The output should be like,

```
sum : 45
avg : 15
min : 8
max : 10
```

Comment: Have a think about what obvious and important piece of information you have omitted from your question.

Comment: What errors are thrown in your code, is it related to OutOfRange exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem in your code is here:

```
textBox5.Text = numbers[-1].ToString();
```

there will be no entry in your array having -1 index.

If you want to show max value in textBox5, you need to do like that:

```
textBox5.Text = numbers[n-1].ToString();
```

if you want to show min value in textBox5, you need to do like that:

```
textBox5.Text = numbers[0].ToString();
```

Thanks!

Comment: n is not the last array index, it will give out of range exception in your case.

Comment: Thanks. But still the problem persisits.
there is a error in the line
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
numbers[i] = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
}

Comment: I got it. In your textBox1, what are you inputting?

Comment: you need input your number with some delimiter, and in your code, you need to split that input string using that delimiter into array.

Comment: I am inputting 34,89,54

Comment: then, you should split this textBox.Text value in array using comma.
String[] array = textBox1.split(",");
and populate your numbers like that:
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
numbers[i] = int.Parse(array[i]);
}

Comment: @Saadi Actually, tatz `string[] array = textBox1.Text.Split(',');` Thanks. I have fixed the error. Now the program is working fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

Set your array i to contain all the values passed in through the user input on your form. You can then use this code to get all the values you want. Then just write the variables iMax, iMin, iSum and flAvg to your output labels. In this example I've just put my own data in to illustrate the code.

```
    int[] i = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int iSum = 0;
    float flAvg = 0.0f;
    int iMax = 0;
    int iMin = Int32.MaxValue;
    foreach (int iElement in i)
    {
        iSum = iSum + iElement;
        flAvg = flAvg + iElement;
        if (iElement > iMax)
        {
            iMax = iElement;
        }
        if (iElement < iMin)
        {
            iMin = iElement;
        }
    }
        flAvg = flAvg / i.Length;
//carry on to do stuff with the data down here.
```

Answer (score 0):

change the code for this line:

```
 textBox5.Text = numbers[n-1].ToString();
```

as -1 is not an index here, your picking the max value here, it will be at n-1 index.

and for the line of code :

```
  numbers[i] = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

use this:

```
numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: This is the error, i am getting in line
`Numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(textbox.Text) `

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.**

Comment: what is the value that you have entered in the textbox, it should be in integer value, as you have not applied any check in the code. So you have to make sure for that case.

Comment: Please can you tell what is the value of Textbox1 and textbox7.

Comment: Your program is not dynamic to read these values in an array as you are providing them. It should create an array for your no.s before actually doing the calculations.

Comment: @saadi has cleared my errors. For Example, Textbox1 value is 21,45,76 **(Set of Numbers according to the range)**. Textbox7 is 3 **(Range)**

Answer (score 0):

Use linq ,is very clean way and work properly :

```
          int n = int.Parse(textBox7.Text); ;
            int[] numbers = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                numbers[i] = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            }
           // var array = new short[] { 4, 4, 5, 6,9 };

            var sum = numbers.Select(x => (int)x).Sum();
            var avg = numbers.Select(x => (int)x).Average();
            var max = numbers.Select(x => (int)x).Max();
            var min = numbers.Select(x => (int)x).Min();

            textBox4.Text = sum.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = avg.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = min.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = max.ToString();
```

Comment: Using Function / Method is prohibited. I should able to do without these

Comment: Can you explain why is prohibited to use Function / Method

Comment: Itz user requirement. They don't need any built in functions.